# Clean hexadecimal entities in a XML doc via PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, character-encoding

I need to send an XML document to a SOAP web service (which I don't have any control of). I was receiving an error because the texts contain html entities, so I clean the strings of text with [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and then [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before I add the text to the simpleXML object, like this:

```
if( !mb_detect_encoding($string, "UTF-8") == "UTF-8" ) {
   $string = utf8_encode($string);
}
$string = htmlspecialchars( html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$xml->addChild('PROD_DESC', $string);
```

But although it cleans named entities in the form `&copy;` it doesn't do anything with hexadecimal entities like `&#xE1;`, and the service I am talking to doesn't accept those either.

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045837/reading-in-malformed-xml-unencoded-xml-entities-with-php) I found a possible solution, but when I pass that string to the tidy cleanString function I get the same string, it doesn't touch those entities either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: using DomDocument whenever I try to write UTF-8 it writes the hexadecimal notation of it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575109/php-using-domdocument-whenever-i-try-to-write-utf-8-it-writes-the-hexadecimal-no)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I hadn't seen that one. You gave a good explanation there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numeric entities are added by SimpleXML because your XML document has no declared encoding:

```
// with declared encoding :
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><x></x>');
$xml->addChild('PROD_DESC', "à");
// result: <PROD_DESC>à</PROD_DESC>

// without declared encoding :
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0"?><x></x>');
$xml->addChild('PROD_DESC', "à");
// result: <PROD_DESC>&#xE0;</PROD_DESC>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. Just one piece left: All the entities are gone except the carriage return: &#13; at the end of every line in those text fields. Why are these entities being inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable for you to pass the string as base64 encoded data? This would eliminate the need to strip anything out.